# Liferay + jboss

Tags: jboss, liferay

I am trying start jboss and I have an error. I use jboss 7.1.1 and Liferay. What is wrong?

```
12:25:26,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBA
S015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 235420ms
12:25:35,754 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeploySca
nner) Exception in thread "com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScann
er" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/types/resources/FailFas
t
12:25:35,785 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeploySca
nner)   at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.BaseResourceCollectionContainer.
iterator(BaseResourceCollectionContainer.java:142)
12:25:35,801 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeploySca
nner)   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:135)
12:25:35,801 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeploySca
nner)   at com.liferay.util.ant.ExpandTask.expand(ExpandTask.java:33)
12:25:35,801 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeploySca
nner)   at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.
java:955)
12:25:35,801 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeploySca
nner)   at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.
java:889)
12:25:35,801 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeploySca
nner)   at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.
java:198)
```

Comment: do u use liferay-jboss bundle??

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: To setup machine for Liferay development first of all you will need to download and install all required software as described below.

```
JAVA (JDK & JRE)
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
 Eclipse IDE   
    http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
Liferay JBOSS bundle (Community Edition or Enterprise Edition as per your requirements and preferences), Liferay Tomcat bundle (For server run time selection), Liferay Plugin SDK (For Development of plugins like hooks, portlets, themes etc.
     http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases
Apache Ant (For build and deployment of projects).
```

Step 2: Now set environment variables in your machine.
       Set JAVA_HOME
       Set JBOSS_HOME
       Set LIFERAY_HOME
       Set ANT_HOME

Step 3: Open Eclipse and install Liferay IDE.
Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
    Search for "Liferay".
  Install Liferay IDE and restart eclipse.

Step 4: To configure Liferay Plugin-SDK
    Go to Window -> Preferences -> Liferay
     Add Liferay Plugin-SDK

```
 Here you will option to update build.<username>.properties file. Select
 prompt.


 That's it your system is ready with development environment for Liferay.
```

Step 6: In Liferay Plugin-SDK folder there will be a file called
     build.username.properties

```
 Set path of server to refer JBOSS directory.
```

Step 7:Create new Liferay Plugin Project.
  Inside that Create New Portlet Project.
Select Liferay Portal Runtime as Tomcat, because Eclipse doesn't provide
   runtime for JBOSS Application server so use some tricky way to deal with it.

```
After clicking on finish it will ask for updating build.<username>.properties file.
Select "No" option.

Okay Now you are done with project creation and Setting  deployment server
as JBOSS.
```

Step 8: Deploy Liferay Portlet Project.
Step 9: Run standalone.bat from bin directory of JBOSS

For more details follow this blog http://liferaywithjboss.blogspot.in/.

Let me know if you need more details for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check your jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in ROOT.war/WEB-INF/ location to see any of the dependency modules mentioned in there uses ant-*.jars. The issue could be due to multiple jars with the same classname in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

new liferay versions provide a wildfly bundle... this could be a starting point, neverthelesse ClassNotFound typically originates from missing jars in that special context, whether physically or suppressed by the jboss modul-system ( starting is here the deployment-structure file, or even worse the module directory of your installation)
but in the end a guy like me decides often to get a new working  environment before diving  into that voluntarily...